# iPhone : Top Navigation bar push the Google logo down the screen

Tags: iphone, google-maps, dictionary

> I am new to iPhone development, please
>   suggest the right way to rectify the below problem.
>
> I am
>   displaying the Google Map as below :

[image]

> Now the problem is the Top Navigation
>   bar pushes the Google logo on Map
>   below screen and hence it is not
>   visible, when I hide the Navigation
>   bar, I can see the Google logo as
>   below

[image]

> Code Reference :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
    self.title =@"Map View";
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.delegate=self;




    /*Region and Zoom*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];    

    location.latitude = [appdelegate.RDLat doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [appdelegate.RDLng doubleValue];

    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;


    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];


    ParkPlaceMark *placemark=[[ParkPlaceMark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location title:appdelegate.RestAddress];
    [mapView addAnnotation:placemark];

    [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];

}
```

> Now Please suggest me how to show
>   Navigation bar without pushing the
>   Google map below.
>
> Any help highly appriciated

Comment: Whaha, I wanted to post this question just now! (like 2 mins apart)

Comment: Oh, and do you add everything in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change below line

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

To

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,44,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
```

And It will work as charm. Let me know if it is not.

Comment: Thank you very much Deeps! I have replaced it but now the a white patch came just below the navigation bar.. the white patch is the same size as navigation bar do I need to do some modification in that code snipet..

Comment: Did you remove Navigation bar ? or change style of Navigation bar ?

Comment: Hi Deeps got it, I just made -44 and every thing is working as expected..thanks for the help!

Comment: Great. I am glad it worked. Still -44 is not a good solution though. You should doing something wrong. Ohh I got it now. I just edited my my answer. Please replace that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of your view : it's too big.
If you built the view using the interface builder, you have to set the *top bar* property of your `UIView` to *Navigation Bar* in the properties panel. This should automatically resize your view. Make sure your map view is resized as well.